# how can i swizzle corefoundation framework methods?

Tags: ios, core-foundation, swizzling

I followed this [article](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) for objective-c method swizzling. I'm successfully able to swizzle methods objective -c class methods. I also want to swizzle core foundation methods like CFHostCreateWithName(). Is it possible to swizzle core foundation methods?

Answer (score 4):

Swizzling does not exist for C function, but there is an equivalent called patching. Unfortunately, it will not work on iOS.

In OS X, A [code injection](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-30-code-injection.html) system like [mach_override](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_override) can be used to patch functions. It's not available for iOS. Even if you could get it to work, Apple would never approve it for the App Store.